# How do I fix this "Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method" error

Tags: java, processing

I'm programming a simple sketch in [processing](http://processing.org/) (a type of java), and using [this](http://wiki.processing.org/w/Listing_files) bit of code to scan a folder for jpgs. I would like to be able to use it as a function, so I can use it like this:

```
String[] images;

void setup() {
  images = scanForJpgs();
}


String[] scanForJpgs() {
  // set target folder
  java.io.File folder = new java.io.File(dataPath(""));

  // set filter (which returns true if file's extension is .jpg)
  java.io.FilenameFilter jpgFilter = new java.io.FilenameFilter() {
    boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
      return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg");
    }
  };

  // list files in target folder, passing the filter as parameter
  String[] filenames = folder.list(jpgFilter);

  return filenames;
}
```

But it throws a "*Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from FilenameFilter*" error. How do I fix this so I can use it like a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the method `public` rather than package-private:

```
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
```

Read: [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: Ah, that did it. Thank you! I'll accept your answer as soon as the timer lets me.